# Кодировка данных полученных из адресной строки

Tags: ajax, кодировка, перекодировка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при интеграции с сервисом почтовых рассылок Unisender:
Сервис сгенерил мне форму подписки:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://api.unisender.com/ru/subscribe?hash=57cynrg8pot9hagjqqcn3un5ocyazzzdhtij9pttc8ysrsrknk5qy" name="subscribtion_form">
<div class="subscribe-form-item subscribe-form-item--input-string">
    <label class="subscribe-form-item__label subscribe-form-item__label--input-string ">Им'я</label>
    <input class="subscribe-form-item__control subscribe-form-item__control--input-string" type="text" name="f_4847986" value="">
</div>
<div class="subscribe-form-item subscribe-form-item--input-email">
    <label class="subscribe-form-item__label subscribe-form-item__label--input-email subscribe-form-item__label--required">E-mail</label>
    <input class="subscribe-form-item__control subscribe-form-item__control--input-email" type="text" name="email" value="">
</div>
<div class="subscribe-form-item subscribe-form-item--btn-submit">
    <input class="subscribe-form-item__btn subscribe-form-item__btn--btn-submit" type="submit" value="отримати маркетинг-кіт">
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="default_list_id" value="8378765">
<input type="hidden" name="overwrite" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="is_v5" value="1">
```

с помощью которой пользователь отдает мне имя и емаил.
После подтверждения подписки пользователь попадает на страницу со следующим адресом:

```
http://www.mysite.xyz/p/befor.html?name=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD
```

все дело в том, что в браузере вместо набора символов после знака равно пишется реальное имя (которое было введено в форму), но когда я его разпарсиваю:

```
    <script>
var stroka = window.location.search.split('=');
$('.befor-subscription').append(stroka[1] + ' Ваше звернення отримано. Наша відповідь не змусить Вас довго чекати. Будь ласка перевірте Ваш email.');
</script>
```

или делаю копипаст от туда сюда я получаю набор символов.
Сапорт сервиса утверждает, что у них все четко передается в UTF-8, и проблема с моей стороны, хотя у меня тоже кодировка UTF-8. Поддержка рекомендует сменить кодировку сайта на windows-1251, но мне кажется это не лучший вариант.

Comment: rawurldecode() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurldecode.php или urldecode(), в зависимости чем `+` у вас является.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам.
Помогло следующее - `var uri = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search)` дальше уже работаем с переменной `uri`